# What kind of syntax is platform.txt from Adafruit_nRF52_Arduino

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, arduino, adafruit

If someone would please tell me what kind of syntax the following file is?

https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_nRF52_Arduino/blob/master/platform.txt

```
name=Adafruit nRF52 Boards
version=0.19.0

# Compile variables
# -----------------

compiler.warning_flags=-w
compiler.warning_flags.none=-w
compiler.warning_flags.default=
compiler.warning_flags.more=-Wall
compiler.warning_flags.all=-Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-pointer-arith

compiler.path={runtime.tools.arm-none-eabi-gcc.path}/bin/
compiler.c.cmd=arm-none-eabi-gcc
compiler.c.flags=-mcpu={build.mcu} -mthumb -c -g {compiler.warning_flags} {build.float_flags} -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -nostdlib --param max-inline-insns-single=500 -MMD
compiler.c.elf.cmd=arm-none-eabi-gcc
compiler.c.elf.flags=-Ofast -Wl,--gc-sections -save-temps
compiler.S.cmd=arm-none-eabi-gcc
compiler.S.flags=-c -g -x assembler-with-cpp
compiler.cpp.cmd=arm-none-eabi-g++
compiler.cpp.flags=-mcpu={build.mcu} -mthumb -c -g {compiler.warning_flags} {build.float_flags} -std=gnu++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -nostdlib --param max-inline-insns-single=500 -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -MMD
compiler.ar.cmd=arm-none-eabi-ar
compiler.ar.flags=rcs
compiler.objcopy.cmd=arm-none-eabi-objcopy
compiler.objcopy.eep.flags=-O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0
compiler.elf2bin.flags=-O binary
compiler.elf2bin.cmd=arm-none-eabi-objcopy
compiler.elf2hex.flags=-O ihex
compiler.elf2hex.cmd=arm-none-eabi-objcopy
compiler.ldflags=-mcpu={build.mcu} -mthumb {build.float_flags} -Wl,--cref -Wl,--check-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=report-all -Wl,--warn-common -Wl,--warn-section-align --specs=nano.specs --specs=nosys.specs
compiler.size.cmd=arm-none-eabi-size

# this can be overriden in boards.txt
build.float_flags=-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -u _printf_float
build.debug_flags=-DCFG_DEBUG=0

# common compiler for nrf
rtos.path={build.core.path}/freertos
nordic.path={build.core.path}/nordic


build.flags.nrf= -DSOFTDEVICE_PRESENT -DARDUINO_NRF52_ADAFRUIT -DNRF52_SERIES -DLFS_NAME_MAX=64 -Ofast {build.debug_flags} "-I{build.core.path}/cmsis/include" "-I{nordic.path}" "-I{nordic.path}/nrfx" "-I{nordic.path}/nrfx/hal" "-I{nordic.path}/nrfx/mdk" "-I{nordic.path}/nrfx/soc" "-I{nordic.path}/nrfx/drivers/include" "-I{nordic.path}/nrfx/drivers/src" "-I{nordic.path}/softdevice/{build.sd_name}_nrf52_{build.sd_version}_API/include" "-I{rtos.path}/Source/include" "-I{rtos.path}/config" "-I{rtos.path}/portable/GCC/nrf52" "-I{rtos.path}/portable/CMSIS/nrf52" "-I{build.core.path}/sysview/SEGGER" "-I{build.core.path}/sysview/Config" "-I{build.core.path}/TinyUSB" "-I{build.core.path}/TinyUSB/Adafruit_TinyUSB_ArduinoCore" "-I{build.core.path}/TinyUSB/Adafruit_TinyUSB_ArduinoCore/tinyusb/src"

# usb flags
build.flags.usb= -DUSBCON -DUSE_TINYUSB -DUSB_VID={build.vid} -DUSB_PID={build.pid} '-DUSB_MANUFACTURER={build.usb_manufacturer}' '-DUSB_PRODUCT={build.usb_product}'

# These can be overridden in platform.local.txt
compiler.c.extra_flags=
compiler.c.elf.extra_flags=
compiler.cpp.extra_flags=
compiler.S.extra_flags=
compiler.ar.extra_flags=
compiler.elf2bin.extra_flags=
compiler.elf2hex.extra_flags=


# Compile patterns
# ----------------

## Compile c files
recipe.c.o.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.c.cmd}" {compiler.c.flags} -DF_CPU={build.f_cpu} -DARDUINO={runtime.ide.version} -DARDUINO_{build.board} -DARDUINO_ARCH_{build.arch} -DARDUINO_BSP_VERSION="{version}" {compiler.c.extra_flags} {build.extra_flags} {build.flags.nrf} {includes} "{source_file}" -o "{object_file}"

snip
```

While building my project with Eclipse Arduino I am having issues with the Makefile that gets created from this file in arduinocdt which I am trying to debug.
There is an issue with macro expansion from ARDUINO_BSP_VERSION (solved)
Another issue is with flashing my built firmware.

Comment: You should never add filler text to a question. Instead try to expand on your question, like adding *why* you wonder about this text file. What is the underlying problem that you're trying to solve? Is it plain curiosity? That's fine, but please add a note about it.

Comment: it is a (Java) .properties file format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties

Answer (score 0):

The file is in fact a Java .properties file and the 3rd party Hardware format [specification](https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/platform-specification/) to be used in Arduino IDE and Eclipse Arduino CDT.